# Is there any way I can use $where with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

Is there any way I can use $where in aggregate.

my collection is {"id":5,score:70}, I tried {$match:{$where:"this.id>5&&this.score>70"}}, but it doesn't work, I have to use where as my api is ainterface to mong,which is receiving query from user in general text like "SQL", so is their any way I can use $where in aggregate because as document say, I cannot use it with $match, it works fine with normal find, but how to make it work with aggregate query?

Comment: $where was specifically avoided, nay removed by JIRA, in the aggregation framework, it simply kills performance

Comment: Use proper rules to make question more presentable, so that it becomes easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you don't need to use `$where` for that:

```js
{'$match': {'id': {'$gt': 5}, 'score': {'$gt': 70}}}
```

So you'd need to have the user enter their query as a JSON string like above and then `JSON.parse` the string on the server to turn it into an object that you could use with `$match`.

As a side note, the performance of `$where` is terrible, so basing an API on `$where` queries is a very bad idea.

Comment: I can do that, but in the case of OR and AND their can be nested AND and OR , so in that case chances of error increases

Comment: @PhalguniMukherjee But the chance of dangerous script injections decreases, which should be even more important.